# Как совместить php и java сервера?

Tags: php, java, nginx, apache, tomcat

Всем привет, ситуация такая есть около 50 проектов на php работает все на nginx + fpm под управление BrainyCP, и подошло 3 проекта стартовых по Java задача такая нужно совместить так что бы и то и то обрабатывалось на 80 порту. Кто имел такую практику, кто мог бы подсказать или указать куда смотреть в каком направлении по поводу этого.

Проблема в том что в google не нахожу то что именно мне нужно.

Ну или если ставить apache tomcat как решить конфликт портов на nginx/apache php?

Надеюсь на адекватный аргументированый ответ, заранее спасибо.

P.S. Не судите строго :)

Comment: Что вам мешает каждому сервису назначить не стандартный порт, отдельный от 80/443?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev а как тогда сделать так что бы пользователь смог войти на сайт/сервис по 80?
допустим внутренний порт php 81 java 83 а внешний как реализовать? всего один сервер на обработке напрямую к роутеру

Comment: Слова для поискв Nginx reverse proxy

Comment: Сделать так, чтобы один и тот же внешний порт роутера вел на две разные машины во внутренней сети или же одну машину, но с разными портами у Вас не получится. Тут только два варианта, либо как уже писал выше @AndreyMihalev разные внешние порты роутера, на разные порты одной внутренней машины или две разные внутренние машины ( внешний 80->192.168.x.2: 80, внешний 81->192.168.x.2: 81), либо разные внешние доменные имена так называемая технология SNI (site1.xyz:80->192.168.x.2: 80, site2.xyz:80->192.168.x.2: 81)